# How to access object property inside array?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

The code below, I wrote in Postman. I would like to get the `created_at` date which shows in the picture I attached. But it keeps giving me the current response date.

```
    const moment = require("moment")
    console.log(pm.response.json(0));
    let timestamp = moment(pm.response.json(0)).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    pm.test("Check if the create_at of id1 timing is correct or not", function () {
     pm.expect(moment(timestamp).to.eql("2020-07-28"));
    });
```

[image: JSON data]

Comment: I haven't used postman the way you are but wouldn't you have to do `pm.response.json(0).created_at`?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights tried. It show undefined error

Comment: If you're accessing an item in an array wouldn't it have to be square brackets? `pm.response.json[0].created_at`

Comment: you're right thanks! got it